# 公開鍵の作成について

Tags: swift, xcode, swift2, xcode7

現在サーバと通信するために公開鍵をアプリ内で作成しようと試みています。
「Security Foundation」を使うことまでわかりました。
実際にサーバに送る内容としては

> -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
>   -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

このような形の公開鍵をString型で送りたいのですが、どの様に作成すればよいのかわかりません。
ご教授願います。

※06/23追記
[teratail](http://teratail.com/questions/38912)
teratailの方にも質問させていただいております。
解決次第両方の質問に解決方法を記載の後クローズさせていただきたいと思っております。

Comment: 以前`SecKeyGeneratePair`を使用したコードを掲載した同趣旨の質問を見た覚えがあるのですが、あなたのご質問ではなかったでしょうか?一般的な傾向として、「自分ではここまでやってみた」といった形で(たとえ誤りが含まれていても)コードを示した方が回答がつきやすいですし、古い質問を削除して新しい質問スレを始める人よりも、質問内容を改善していこうという姿勢を見せてくださる方が、より沢山の回答が集まる傾向があります。単に私の記憶違いであればご容赦を。

Comment: 気をつけてほしいのが当サイト(SO)ではクローズの意味合いが違います。SOでのクローズとは現状の質問では回答がつかないので要編集状態で差し戻された状態です。解決済みのマークには"承認"機能を用います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func sample() {
    let begin: String = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\r\n"
    let finish: String = "\r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"

    heimdall = Heimdall(publicTag: "publicKey", privateTag: "privateKey", keySize: 1024)
    let publicKeyData = heimdall?.publicKeyDataX509()
    let base64 = publicKeyData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
    let publicKeyString = begin + base64 + finish
}
```

CocoaPodsのHeimdallというフレームワークを利用することで、
自己解決出来ました。
根本的な解決には至っていませんが代用させていただきます。

SecurityFrameworkを利用する方法でも作成は出来たのですが、
途中の設定がおかしいのか長さを指定しても少し短いのができてしまいました。